# Are there any Conv Net tutorials that do not use any frameworks?

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

My first intro to ML and DL was last year in Udacity/Coursera and using TensorFlow.  I have to admit I learned many things, but none of these things were cemented until I read through [Michael Nielson's](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html) book on Neural Nets and DL.

The ideas were only cemented because I followed along his python/numpy examples and then "copied" these techniques [as best I can](https://github.com/RazazRobotics/untitled-/blob/master/src/main.c) using C with only the stdlib .

I did so because I wanted to practice coding in C.  You can bet that I now understand how to handle `SEGFAULTS`/`SIGSEGV` a whole of lot better than when I started this over one month ago.

I was able to understand more of the details of SGD/backprop for vanilla feedforward nets, because I practiced them.

Unfortunately when it came to Conv Nets he moved straight into Theano.

So now I am looking for detailed discussions into convolutions, im2col, pooling, SGD/backprop etc, that do not use any framework and only describe the equations and algorithms (and hopefully some sample code in `python/numpy` and even better in `C/C++`).

Please understand I am not trying to write my own library or framework.  I am simply trying to get a strong deep foundational knowledge on these topics.  I believe that can only be achieved by practicing them with `python/numpy` or C or any language of choice.

Then I can build upon that with a framework like TF/PyTorch/Theano to experiment with hyper parameter tuning, etc.

Comment: The [CS 231n course](http://cs231n.github.io/) is pretty good.

Comment: Thanks for the book, amazing one, bookmarked!

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://towardsdatascience.com/building-convolutional-neural-network-using-numpy-from-scratch-b30aac50e50a) perhaps. Alternatively, just look up "implement a CNN in numpy"

Comment: Of course I did! I also wanted to get advice from the community